# Properly using constructors in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list

I have a simple assignment function as follows:

```
LinkedList& LinkedList::operator=(const LinkedList &l) {
    // handle self assignment
    if (this == &l) {
        return *this;
    }

    // free old elements of the list before the new elements from l are assigned
    ~*this();

    // build the list as a deep copy of l (copy constructor handles empty case)
    this(l);

    return *this;
}
```

and whenever I run my program I get a `error: ‘this’ cannot be used as a function` response. How do am I supposed to use the constructors in their actual context? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can just use `std::list`. It is a linked list.

Comment: The very idea is bad. See this: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/023.htm

Comment: Just copy and swap. Easier and not broken

Comment: NO_NAME: Just trying to learn the tricks of the trade :) @Fred Larson Would making separate functions to handle all of the functionality be better, or could I just use what I have? Maybe in assignment of a new list? Alan Stokes: Where does the "swap" come into play?

Comment: @T145: See [another GOTW article for how to use a swap](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/059.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for what you're attempting is:

```
this->~LinkedList();  
new(this) LinkedList(l);
```

You've clearly realized that it's good to avoid code duplication, however the preferred way to go about it is to use the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) to write the assignment operator.

Comment: I think the destructor/new version is valid code, however if the `new` throws then you end up in a horrible mess, so there is good reason to avoid it.

Comment: So all I need is `swap(*this, &l); return *this;`?

Comment: @T145 yes, but without the `&`.  And the assignment operator function should take `l` by value (not by reference).

Answer (score 3):

Manual calling constructors or destructors is almost always a very bad idea. They are not designed to it.

You should create separate functions to clearing and copying the list. Constructor and destructor can use these methods.